# jquery disable drop on some elements

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

i am trying to disable drop an element on ".buildingWrapper" divs, but the drop must be inside the ".starWrapper" div!

```
$( ".menuBuilding" ).draggable({ 
    containment: ".gameWrapper",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {

    },
});


$(".buildingWrapper").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var elm = ui.draggable;

        if ($(this).attr("class") == 'buildingWrapper') {
            ui.draggable = $("<div style='background: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px;'></div>");
        } else {
            ui.draggable = $(elm);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share the html also, if possible a [fiddle also](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: a better one http://jsfiddle.net/S6Tzm/1/